# Result of "rsync"

Tags: scripts, rsync

I need to create a script that executes periodically (every 5 seconds) a rsync between two directories.

One requirement is that I need to write, with a timestamp, the copied files into a log file but I cannot find a way to get a *result* of the `rsync` copied files. Is there a way to know which files have been copied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-v` (`--verbose`) option of `rsync` to get which files are being copied.

To get *specific* output, `rsync` has the `--info` option.

For example, to get only the files that were supposed to be copied, successful/unseccessful both shown:

```
rsync --info=name /source /destination
```

To get only transfer stat:

```
rsync --info=stat /source /destination
```

You can use uppercase in the option value too (e.g `--info=NAME`) and append `2` after option value to increase verbosity, if possible (e.g `--info=NAME2`).

There are a lot of other possibilities too, check `man rsync` and especially `rsync --info=help`:

```
% rsync --info=help
Use OPT or OPT1 for level 1 output, OPT2 for level 2, etc.; OPT0 silences.

BACKUP     Mention files backed up
COPY       Mention files copied locally on the receiving side
DEL        Mention deletions on the receiving side
FLIST      Mention file-list receiving/sending (levels 1-2)
MISC       Mention miscellaneous information (levels 1-2)
MOUNT      Mention mounts that were found or skipped
NAME       Mention 1) updated file/dir names, 2) unchanged names
PROGRESS   Mention 1) per-file progress or 2) total transfer progress
REMOVE     Mention files removed on the sending side
SKIP       Mention files that are skipped due to options used
STATS      Mention statistics at end of run (levels 1-3)
SYMSAFE    Mention symlinks that are unsafe

ALL        Set all --info options (e.g. all4)
NONE       Silence all --info options (same as all0)
HELP       Output this help message

Options added for each increase in verbose level:
1) COPY,DEL,FLIST,MISC,NAME,STATS,SYMSAFE
2) BACKUP,MISC2,MOUNT,NAME2,REMOVE,SKIP
```

---

**Example:**

```
% rsync --info=name test.txt foobar:/spamegg/
test.txt

% rsync --info=stats test.txt foobar:/spamegg/
sent 86 bytes  received 41 bytes  254.00 bytes/sec
total size is 10  speedup is 0.08
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-v` flag, in addition to whatever other flags you need.

From [`man rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync):

> **-v, --verbose**
>   This option increases the amount of information you are given during the transfer. By default, rsync works silently. A single **-v** will give you information about what files are being transferred and a brief summary at the end. Two **-v** options will give you information on what files are being skipped and slightly more information at the end....

Answer (score 0):

In case some one ever needs it... After many tests I am going for something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm out.log
touch out.log
while :
do
rsync --log-file=out.log -a /tmp/test /tmp/backup
counter=`wc -l < out.log`
echo $counter
rm out.log
if [[ $counter -gt 2 ]]; then
rsync --log-file=out.log -a /tmp/test /tmp/backup
fi
sleep 5
done
```